# How to add php ordering parameters to the URL?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a plugin that enables comment rating for wordpress and I want to be able to have 4 links on the post;

- newest comment
- oldest comment
- highest rated
- lowest rated

which will change the order of the comments accordingly.

I know that the links should read something like

- www.example.com?orderby=comment_date&order=ASC
- www.example.com?orderby=comment_date&order=DESC
- www.example.com?orderby=comment_rating&order=ASC
- www.example.com?orderby=comment_rating&order=DESC

The thing is, when it comes to php I'm a complete novice so I was wondering what do i have to change/add here;

```
<ol class="commentlist">
<?php if (function_exists(ckrating_get_comments))
{$post_id = $post->ID;$mycomments=ckrating_get_comments("post_id=$post_id&status=approve&orderby=comment_date&order=ASC");}
else$mycomments = null;wp_list_comments(array(), $mycomments);?>
</ol>
```

in order to make the above work? Or do I need to change something in here;

```
function ckrating_get_comments( $args = '' ) {
global $wpdb;

$defaults = array('status' => '', 'orderby' => 'comment_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'number' => '', 'offset' => '', 'post_id' => 0);

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

// $args can be whatever, only use the args defined in defaults to compute the key
$key = md5( serialize( compact(array_keys($defaults)) )  );
$last_changed = wp_cache_get('last_changed', 'comment');
if ( !$last_changed ) {
    $last_changed = time();
    wp_cache_set('last_changed', $last_changed, 'comment');
}
$cache_key = "get_comments:$key:$last_changed";

if ( $cache = wp_cache_get( $cache_key, 'comment' ) ) {
    return $cache;
}

$post_id = absint($post_id);

if ( 'hold' == $status )
    $approved = "comment_approved = '0'";
elseif ( 'approve' == $status )
    $approved = "comment_approved = '1'";
elseif ( 'spam' == $status )
    $approved = "comment_approved = 'spam'";
else
    $approved = "( comment_approved = '0' OR comment_approved = '1' )";

$order = ( 'ASC' == $order ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

    $orderby = (isset($orderby)) ? $orderby : 'comment_rating';  

$number = absint($number);
$offset = absint($offset);

if ( !empty($number) ) {
    if ( $offset )
        $number = 'LIMIT ' . $offset . ',' . $number;
    else
        $number = 'LIMIT ' . $number;

} else {
    $number = '';
}

if ( ! empty($post_id) )
    $post_where = $wpdb->prepare( 'comment_post_ID = %d AND', $post_id );
else
    $post_where = '';

$comments = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE $post_where $approved ORDER BY $orderby $order $number" );
wp_cache_add( $cache_key, $comments, 'comment' );

return $comments;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i dont see anything in the code you posted which has to do with creating links. but then again, i have no clue about wordpress either

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <ol class="commentlist">
<?php if (function_exists(ckrating_get_comments))
{
$order_by = mysql_real_escape_string((isset($_GET['orderby']) ? $_GET['orderby'] : 'comment_date' ));
$order = mysql_real_escape_string((isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'ASC'));

$post_id = $post->ID;$mycomments=ckrating_get_comments("post_id=$post_id&status=approve&orderby=" . $order_by . "order=" . $order);}
else$mycomments = null;wp_list_comments(array(), $mycomments);?>
</ol>
```

Comment: although this ome is "closer" to working, its the only answer where the page doesn't break, only trouble is that the comments dont load

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve waht your trying to do is modifying the first code

```
<ol class="commentlist">
<?php if (function_exists(ckrating_get_comments))
{$post_id = $post->ID;$mycomments=ckrating_get_comments("post_id=$post_id&status=approve&orderby=".(isset($_GET['comment_date']) ? $_GET['comment_date'] ? 'comment_date')."&order=".(isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] ? 'ASC'));}
else$mycomments = null;wp_list_comments(array(), $mycomments);?>
</ol>
```

When you call those for link, the values of the two parameters "comment_date" and "order" are in the $_GET global variable.

Answer (score 0):

As Petro mentioned, your code does not provide a way to manipulate the links you asked for, but that may be sinple enough for you to add.

To implement the query, change this:

```
"post_id=$post_id&status=approve&orderby=comment_date&order=ASC"
```

to this:

```
"post_id=$post_id&status=approve&orderby=" . isset($_GET['orderby']) ? $_GET['orderby'] : 'comment_date' . "&order=" . isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'ASC';
```

That will allow you to pass get vars. I'm not sure if you need to escape anything here. Wordpress may handle that automatically. Don't take my word for it though.