# Wordpress ordering posts by meta key

Tags: wordpress

This has been confusing me no end.

I have this query on a page, works fine to order posts by meta_value.

```
query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'epicredrank', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ,  'paged' => $paged, ) );
```

Trying to create a link to order the posts like this and it isn't working.

```
 <a class="voted-on" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?meta_key=epicredrank&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC">
                    <span>Hot Posts</span>
                </a>
```

It doesn't re-order anything, the query, when passed to the URL seems to do nothing at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit- Want to sort posts by meta value via a link.

Comment: use `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` not `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'`

Comment: Have a look at this 
[Filtering and sorting by meta key][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352001/search-using-custom-fields-in-wordpress/20354049#20354049

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<a class="voted-on" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?meta_key=epicredrank&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC"><span>Hot Posts</span></a>`

```
  $meta_key = mysql_real_escape_string((isset($_GET['meta_key']) ? $_GET['meta_key'] : 'epicredrank' ));
  $order_by = mysql_real_escape_string((isset($_GET['orderby']) ? $_GET['orderby'] : 'meta_value_num' ));
  $order = mysql_real_escape_string((isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'DESC'));

  query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => $meta_key, 'orderby' => $order_by, 'order' => $order ,  'paged' => $paged ) );
```

Comment: <a class="voted-on" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?orderby=epicredrank&order=DESC"> ? Doesn't work, can you write it out?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, just orders the posts in chronological order from first to last, same as they are anyway.

Comment: Have you tried like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718684/how-to-add-php-ordering-parameters-to-the-url

Comment: Which answer are you referring to?

Comment: Uh, not really sure how to implement that or how it's relevant to what I need to do :/

Comment: That just changes the main query on the page and re-orders the posts anyway.

Comment: Try to echo query and see what haapened. :(